# Jekyll: adding url and baseurl to post images and links

Tags: markdown, jekyll

Is there a way to have Jekyll apply the `baseurl` to image and link urls in markdown?

Here's the markdown syntax I want to use:

```
[![some image alt title](/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/my_image.jpg)](/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/my_image.jpg)
```

This should be deployed in a folder (id: http://example.com/portfolio) using `baseurl: portfolio` in _config.yaml. The problem is that the image and link URLs are not being given the relative_url when the page renders:

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/my_image.jpg"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/my_image.jpg" alt="some image alt title"></a>
```

However, it works if I use the link tag:

```
[![some image alt title]({% link /wp-content/uploads/2013/08/my_image.jpg %})](/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/my_image.jpg)
```

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/my_image.jpg"><img src="/portfolio/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/my_image.jpg" alt="some image alt title"></a>
```

The posts have hundreds of images (some with links, some without) and I'd rather not have to change all of the markdown. Is there a way to get the same effect programmatically in Jekyll?

Comment: `{% link %}` is really the built-in way to do what you want and prevent exactly the problem you now have... I'm not aware of another solution, other than some brittle sed trickery maybe?

Comment: sed is what I'm trying to avoid. A quick grep tells me I have 275 links in my markdown that would need to be updated to use the `{% link %}` format.